# How to create or filter for Linq to SQL in C# for a given collection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have three parameters and one `IQueryable<T>`.

My parameters are:

- Title
- ProductTypes
- PricingLevel

As you can see, the **ProductTypes** is an array itself.

I need to filter items that their title contains the given title, that have the given pricing level and that match any of the given product types.

In other words, I need this filter:

```
Title and (ProductType1 or ProductTye2 or ProductType3 or ...) and PricingLevel
```

Here's my code:

```
// query is IQueryable<Product>

query = query.Where(i => i.Title.Contains(title))

foreach (var productType in productTypes)
{
    query = query.Where(i => i.ProductTypesCsv.Contains(productType)) // here I need OR, instead of And
}

query = query.Where(i => i.PricingLevel == PricingLevel)
```

How can I use `OR` in the middle section?

Comment: Marked as duplicate of what seems to be a similar issue, seeing the name `i.ProductTypesCsv`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your foreach loop and change your query for

```
query = query.Where(i => productTypes.Any(pt => i.ProductType == pt));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My bad. I need the `Contians` instead of `==` and I updated the question. This code won't work for `Contains`. `query.Where(i => i.productTypes.Any(pt => i.ProductTypesCsv.Contains(pt)))` throws error of not being translatable.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Contains` for such filter:

```cs
query = query.Where(i => productTypes.Contains(i.ProductType));
```

Comment: This won't work. There is no such a thing as `i.ProductType`. We have a CSV called `i.ProductTypesCsv` and it can be `Electronics,Expensive,SafeForKids`. It's a collection of values.

Comment: Update question with entity model which are trying to filter.